# accessing method skillet.toString() in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
    //Private Property
    var isHot = true;

    //Public Property
    skillet.ingredient = "Bacon Strips";

    //Public Method
    skillet.fry = function() {
        var oliveOil;

        addItem( "\t\n Butter \n\t" );
        addItem( oliveOil );
        console.log( "Frying " + skillet.ingredient );
    };

    //Private Method
    function addItem( item ) {
        if ( item !== undefined ) {
            console.log( "Adding " + $.trim(item) );
        }
    }    
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));



//Adding New Functionality to the Skillet
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {
    //Private Property
    var amountOfGrease = "1 Cup";

    //Public Method
    skillet.toString = function() {
        console.log( skillet.quantity + " " + 
                     skillet.ingredient + " & " + 
                     amountOfGrease + " of Grease" );
        console.log( isHot ? "Hot" : "Cold" );
    };    
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

for this js code

i can access skillet.fry();

Adding Butter
Frying Bacon Strips

but not skillet.toString();

it will only return

"[object Object]"

is there any way i can access private members

such as oliveOIl or isHot ?

Comment: *it will only return "[object Object]"* - no, it's not, if [used properly](http://jsfiddle.net/5up5N/). *is there any way i can access private members* - if you need to access them, why make them private without providing any getters?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make isHot and oliveOil public properties of skillet, or else you cannot reach them.

I would change:

```
var isHot = true;
```

to:

```
this.isHot = true;
```

Change:

```
var oliveOil;
```

to:

```
this.oliveOil = null;
```

And then you could acces them outside the skillet function as either window.skillet.isHot | window.skillet.fry.oliveOil or skillet().isHot | skillet().fry.oliveOil.

I'm not 100% sure on all of that last stuff, but it should work, in theory. Hey, I tried.